# NSUserDefaults is persistent?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a big problem with `NSUserDefaults` : I receive a feedback from an user who just updated the application from AppStore and he complained that some of the values from `NSUserDefaults` are gone.

There is a little possibility that the `NSUserDefaults` lose some data after application update? 
I read about this problem and some guys have this problem too, but I don't receive a clear answer.

Thanks

Comment: What are you storing in `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Just some dictionaries.

Comment: Containing what information?  Are they app settings or user data?

Comment: Just saving some objects represented in dictionary form. The number of them is set by the application user.

Comment: The main idea is that the number is not a problem. I had more than 3000 of this kind of objects and not causing me any problems. I am very curious if this number will represent a problem when the application is updated from AppStore.

Comment: Sounds like user data, which shouldn't be stored using `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I shouldn't but for me it's more wrong to start to delete from NSUserDefaults just because I did this.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` are not usually reset unless the user deletes the app.

For basic data, NSUserDefaults is the best way to save data such as preferences, dates, strings etc. If you need to save images and files, the file system is better. (`NSCoding`)

If you have large datasets you should use CoreData or SQL on an separate server.

Comment: Same answer everywhere. And when I mean same answer, it's exactly same.I understand for what is NSUserDefaults used for, but I need an answer because it's very annoying my situation.

Comment: @ChirilaVasile - It's not exactly the same - I provided a little more information. But you are right, maybe you shouldn't have asked a question that was already answered?

Comment: Nobody had a clear answer : I know that we can't know what is really happening but I am very curious if large data in NSUserDefaults can really affects it's persistence. If does, I'm gonna be mad :)

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to store? how large?

Comment: I am just saving some dictionaries, not NSData or something like this. Just some dictionaries (from my point of view, I cannot consider these large data, but for NSUserDefaults probably is?)

Comment: You should use NSKeyedArchiver and NSCoding - it's pretty easy to implement!

Comment: It's not about implementing because I can do Core Data or a .plist file.

Comment: Do you think that using NSKeyedArchiver to encrypt data for writing into file is a safer mode? Are you sure I won't lose data?